# Having Trouble Converting Function to Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'd like to make the following an extension of NSURL instead of a function but I'm getting errors that I can't use the variables. How would I fix this?

The function gets the query string of a url and returns a dictionary with key value pairs of the parameters in the query.

```
func getKeyVals(url:NSURL) -> Dictionary<String, String>{
    var results = [String:String]()
    var keyValues = url.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("&")
    if keyValues?.count > 0 {
        for pair in keyValues! {
            let kv = pair.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
            if kv.count > 1 {
                results.updateValue(kv[1], forKey: kv[0])
            }
        }

    }
    return results
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension NSURL {
    func getKeyVals() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        var results = [String:String]()
        let keyValues = query?.componentsSeparatedByString("&")
        if keyValues?.count > 0 {
            for pair in keyValues! {
                let kv = pair.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
                if kv.count > 1 {
                    results.updateValue(kv[1], forKey: kv[0])
                }
            }

        }
        return results
    }
}

if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.domain.com/index.php?device=iPad&capacity=128GB&color=white"){
    let keyVals = checkedUrl.getKeyVals()   // ["color": "white", "device": "iPad", "capacity": "128GB"]
}
```

Comment: I didn't put the function in. Okay, new to this. Thanks for your help!